# Signed distance from vector direction and signed offset from vector start

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let v be vector from (0,0) to A and B be any point. How to calcule the signed distance to the direction of v and sign be lift or right looking forward aligned to the vector. And signed offset from 0,0 to closest point to B on v's direction?